# Reading a string without wasting memory

Tags: c, string, memory-management

I have to read a string from stdin, allocating memory dinamically without wasting it.
I've done this, but i'm not convinced about it,because in this way i think i waste memory!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *alloc_memory(int n)
{
    char *p;
    p=malloc(n*sizeof(char));
    if(p==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error in malloc\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return p;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s \n",argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char string[64];
    int lung;
    char *p,*s,*w;

    printf("Insert string: \n");

    p=fgets(string,63,stdin);
    if(p==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error in fgets\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("You've inserted: %s", string);

    lung=strlen(p);

    s = alloc_memory(lung+1);

    w=strncpy(s,p,lung);

    printf("Final string:%s", w);   

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

any idea? Should i read one character at a time?

Comment: What memory do you think you're wasting? (Apart from the obvious leak.)

Comment: the memory allocated with char string[64]

Comment: One character at a time will be much slower (and user will get irritated :P) than your approach. You are not wasting any memory, other than the fact that your program is allocating dynamic memory continuously without ever releasing it (which is bad^infinity).

Comment: @SayemAhmed this is only a part of the program...i have to use the string for do other things then;) at the end i will call a free()

Comment: Do you have any special requirment to use `strncpy()` but `strcpy()`? I ask this as `strncpy()` most propably does not do what you expect, at least in certain corner-cases. I advise to reread its man-page.

Comment: You can probably `fgets(string,64,stdin);`, because fgets will read up to n-1 characters (so 63) and append a `\0`. Note that fgets *will* add the newline to the returned string if the user uses the newline to confirm.

Comment: @alk i used strncpy because it is more convenient for me

Comment: @Butterfly: I **strongly** recommend to **reread `man strncpy`** as the current code as is (including my version) provokes undefined behaviour! It's just bad luck it seems to work. You could prove this by running the program under the memory checker Valgrind: http://valgrind

Comment: For this? Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n  bytes
       of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated.

Comment: @Butterfly: Exactly that's the dangerous "feature" of `strncpy()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have `char str[64]` (`string` is not a good name for a variable, it might lead to ambiguities) declared only temporarily just put it in a local context:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * alloc_memory(size_t n)
{
  char * p = malloc(n); /* * sizeof(char) is always 1 */

  if (p == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error in malloc() when trying to allocate %zu bytes.\n", n);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  memset(p, 0, n); /* Avoid having strncpy() choke .. later down in this example. */

  return p;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  if (argc != 1)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s \n", argv[0]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  {
    char * w = NULL;

    printf("Insert string: ");

    {
      char str[64]; /* here str is allocated */
      char * p = fgets(str, 63, stdin);
      if (p == NULL)
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in fgets().\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      printf("You've inserted: '%s'\n", str);

      {
        size_t lung = strlen(p);
        char * s = alloc_memory(lung + 1);

        w = strncpy(s, p, lung);
      }
    } /* here "str" is deallocated */

    printf("Final string: '%s'\n", w);
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Or you can malloc() `string` and then free() it once the data is copied to a new buffer.

Comment: @Butterfly: Please see my comment (on the usage of `strncpy()`) to your question.

Comment: Btw, a local scope is sometimes a hint that it should be split into its own function. In this case, something like `char* read_alloc_line(FILE* f);`

Comment: In `alloc_memory`, why not use `calloc` rather than `malloc` and save the `memset`?